# Iphone dev - Quick setter/getter q

Tags: iphone, automatic-ref-counting

In this code:

```
@synthesize username, password, sliderLabel;

-(IBAction) sliding: (id) sender;
{
    UISlider *s = (UISlider*)sender;
    int value = (int) s.value;

    NSString *newLabel = [ [NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", value];

    sliderLabel.text = newLabel;


}
```

I synthesize username and password and it does the getter and setters itself.
But then I create an UISlider and can do s.value....

So two questions:

1.
Am I wrong in thinking like this:
username is an UITextField - an object.
This object has variables so when we property - and - synthesize the username variable, all its(the objects) variables get setters/getters - so I can do username.text etc?
If I am wrong - then how is it?

2.
Why am I able to do s.value? It just feels wrong.
I had to synthesize username, password and sliderLabel.. but I could instantly do s.value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.
you can get and change all (not the read only) properties of userName (UITextFiels object) because the UITextFiels class has got setter and getter methods for all its properties

2.
when you call `s.value` you are just calling the getter method in UISlider class...
you are just calling: `[s value];` (=meaning getValue)

that's why apple used synthesize when it created the UISlider class for the var/property "value", so you can access to it with the public getter and setter methods

Comment: 1. So what I said IS correct? It seems like that's basically what you wrote? Because of synthesize, getter and setters are created for the variables in username (a UITextField object).2. But I never did synthesize on the variable s. UISlider *s is something I did in that method

Comment: not really. when you synthetize username you don't create setter/getter for the vars in username! you create get/set FOR username. so other classes can instantiate and use your class (with username) and use/set/get yourClass.username (the same way you can use s.value)

Comment: But then the synthesize is not needed here? For example, I never get/set the actual variable sliderLabel, but I do sliderLabel.text. So the synthesize isn't needed?

Comment: you need it (almost) just if you want that other classes using your class can access to that vars... it's a nice way to let your private var to become public/accessible

Comment: Just one last little question.. In the tutorials I'm watching, in the first one he put (in viewDidUnload): self.LabelVariable = nil. But never wrote anything there again for the rest of the tutorials (so far). It's commented: "Release any retained subviews of the main view. E.g. self.myOutlet = nil" I'm not really sure when/What to write there.

Comment: that's because it declared that property with retain, so you have to release it, and setting it to nil means that you release it and then you point to a nil address (that's done magically in the setter method for you)

Comment: But theres a dealloc method where you have to release stuff (in the tutorial). I don't have to? I'm using ARC

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8512/discussion-between-user1021085-and-meronix)

Comment: no, if you use ARC then you don't need to call a release... but setting it to nil when you don't intend to use it again is a good idea anyway...

Comment: But viewdidunload is when you hit the home button? Then you can/will use it again? Also in the code with the label = nil, I could hit the home button and the app still worked

Comment: I'll make a new question. This question was answered. I'll pick yours as the answer.

Comment: no. in apple doc: viewDidUnload:
When a low-memory condition occurs and the current view controller’s views are not needed, the system may opt to remove those views from memory. This method is called after the view controller’s view has been released and is your chance to perform any final cleanup. If your view controller stores separate references to the view or its subviews, you should use this method to release those references. You can also use this method to remove references to any objects that you created to support the view but that are no longer needed...